# Use mutate case_when() in a specific range of columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a large data frame that looks like the df1.
I want to search in the range of columns between col2:col4 (col2,col3,col4)if any character contains the string ***S***.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(position=c(100,200,300),
             correction=c("62M89S", 
                          "8M1D55M88S",
                          "1S25M1S36M89S"))

df1 <- df %>% 
  separate(correction, into = str_c("col", 1:5), 
           sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", fill = "left", remove = FALSE)

df1
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   position correction    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1      100 62M89S        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  62M   89S  
#> 2      200 8M1D55M88S    <NA>  8M    1D    55M   88S  
#> 3      300 1S25M1S36M89S 1S    25M   1S    36M   89S
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I want my data to look like this

```
df1
#>   position correction    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5     inner_S
#>      <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>      
#> 1      100 62M89S        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  62M   89S         NO 
#> 2      200 8M1D55M88S    <NA>  8M    1D    55M   88S         NO
#> 3      300 1S25M1S36M89S 1S    25M   1S    36M   89S         YES
```

since there is the character ***1S*** in col3.

I tried this, but I am sure I am violating some properties

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(col2:col4),
                             ~inner_S=case_when(grepl("S",.) ~ "Yes", 
                              TRUE ~ "No"
                            ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**dplyr**'s `c_across` is very handy for operations like this:

```
df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(inner_S = ifelse(any(grepl('S', c_across(col1:col4))), 'YES', 'NO'))

  position correction    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  inner_S
     <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1      100 62M89S        NA    NA    NA    62M   89S   NO     
2      200 8M1D55M88S    NA    8M    1D    55M   88S   NO     
3      300 1S25M1S36M89S 1S    25M   1S    36M   89S   YES
```

Comment: Careful, the result is a grouped tibble, might want to use an `ungroup` in there

Answer (score 2):

Please find another possible solution using `data.table`

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, inner_S := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) fifelse(any(grepl("S", x)), "YES", "NO")), .SDcols = paste0("col", 2:4)][]
```

- Output

```
#>    position    correction col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 inner_S
#> 1:      100        62M89S <NA> <NA> <NA>  62M  89S      NO
#> 2:      200    8M1D55M88S <NA>   8M   1D  55M  88S      NO
#> 3:      300 1S25M1S36M89S   1S  25M   1S  36M  89S     YES
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @LDT you are very welcome. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by jdobres is perfect. Here is a more complicated one using `across`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(col1:col4, ~ifelse(
    str_detect(., 'S'), TRUE, FALSE), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(inner_S, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate(inner_S = ifelse(str_detect(inner_S, 'TRUE'), "YES", "NO"))
```

```
  position correction    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  inner_S
     <dbl> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1      100 62M89S        NA    NA    NA    62M   89S   NO     
2      200 8M1D55M88S    NA    8M    1D    55M   88S   NO     
3      300 1S25M1S36M89S 1S    25M   1S    36M   89S   YES
```

Comment: thank you TarJee it looks perfect

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `rowwise` approach which can be quite costly when working with larger data sets is to sum the `TRUE` values.

```
df1 %>%
      mutate(inner_S = ifelse(rowSums(across(col1:col4, str_detect, "S"), na.rm = T) > 1, "YES", "NO"))
```